# how to validate data on drop event of itemselecter in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

we not like to add three word again in selected item. 
we like to validate on drag and drop event and need to show message that u already added this record.
i try with below code but not able to fine relevant event for validate

```
listeners: {
            added:function(obj,event){  
                  console.log("added");  
             },change:function(obj,event){  
                  console.log("change");  
             },removed:function(obj,event){  
                  console.log("removed");  
             }, blur:function(obj,event){  
                  console.log("blur");  
             }, click: function( obj) {  
                  console.log('click');   
             }, select: function( obj) {  
                   console.log('select');   
             }  
   }
```

please see attached image bellow.

[image]

I am Using Extjs 3.4

Comment: Why do you offer it twice in the available items, if you don't want it to be selected twice?

Comment: because there are two different list method call. we not know which item selected earlier

Comment: If I were you I would filter the items available for selection to avoid doublons, instead of preventing the user from being able to selected them afterward.

Answer (score 0):

The [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-event-change) event fires when an item is selected or deselected... But at this stage, you won't be able to prevent it anymore. So, apparently, your best move is to override the [`onAddBtnClick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector-method-onAddBtnClick) method:

```
{
    xtype: 'itemselector'

    // ... config

    ,onAddBtnClick: function() {
        var me = this,
            selected = me.getSelections(me.fromField.boundList),
            i, l, record;

        var toStore = this.toField.boundList.getStore(),
            idField = 'value', // or 'id', or whatever you want
            selectedIds = Ext.pluck(Ext.pluck(toStore.getRange(), 'data'), idField),
            accepted = [], rejected = [];

        for (i=0, l=selected.length; i<l; i++) {
            record = selected[i];
            if (selectedIds.indexOf(record.get(idField)) === -1) {
                accepted.push(record);
            } else {
                rejected.push(record);
            }
        }

        if (rejected.length) {
            // warning msg
        }

        me.moveRec(true, accepted);
        me.toField.boundList.getSelectionModel().select(accepted);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but application build on 3.4 now we can't change entire app in 4.XX

Comment: Of course, what I meant is you should state the version you're using, especially if it is not the last one released by Sencha.